# Find a dataset in an R library

Tags: r, dataset

I want to use `library(rethinking); data(Howell1)` without actually compiling the `rethinking` library. It is [not available](https://www.google.com/search?q=rethinking&domains=r-project.org&sitesearch=r-project.org&btnG=Google+Search) on CRAN.

When I clone the library and search for the dataset, I am surprised to find no definition:

```
git clone https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking.git
$ ack Howell
    book_code_boxes.txt
    235:data(Howell1)
    236:d <- Howell1
    321:data(Howell1)
    322:d <- Howell1
    391:data(Howell1)
    392:d <- Howell1
    567:data(Howell1)
    568:d <- Howell1
    628:plot( height ~ weight , data=Howell1 ,
    1073:data(Howell1)
    1074:d <- Howell1
    1401:data(Howell1)
```

The first of those mentions is:

```
library(rethinking)
data(Howell1)
```

As an R newbie, I am surprised to not be able to pull the data and it's sources directly from source code. How do I **read the code** to find the data's source?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but if you go the URL in your code [https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking.git](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking.git) and then follow the link for `data` you can download a csv file for the Howell1 data.

Comment: @G5W I read through `book_code_boxes.txt` and it has nothing to do with that dataset. Seems like name `data` is magic and looked for during the compilation process. As you comment solved my problem , you should post it as an answer.